# File Uploaded via File System using API REST

Tags: java, rest, upload, header, jax-rs

I am newbie in Java EE and I'd like a user to upload a file XML by its file system. My app is using API REST.The file to upload is successfully uploaded to the server (in localhost) but I notice some metadata information is a part of this new file so it gets stuck there!

Example: To upload a file "web.xml", here is what is added to the header and end of the new file (server side)

```
Header:
------WebKitFormBoundarybi7qp5AIFEXbebt7
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="datafile"; filename="web.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

End of new file
------WebKitFormBoundarybi7qp5AIFEXbebt7--
```

See below HTML client file and server side code

```
Client.HTML

</body>
<form action="rest/file/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <p>
        Entrer un fichier xml:<br>
        <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
    </p>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

We've got this above 'Client.HTML' via a simple GET method from server. When submitting the form, the POST method below is called

```
UploadService.java
@Path("/file")
public class UploadService {
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Produces("text/html")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    String uploadedFileLocation = "D:\\rest.xml";

    InputStream in;
    try {

        in = request.getInputStream();
        // save it
        writeToFile(in, uploadedFileLocation);

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

// save uploaded file to new location
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Any help or tricks to solve it, please?

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem i have faced for uploading `JSON`

The Mistake Might be you using a normal method of writing a file as **output** to your place **:**  is by making an `x.xml` file at a location and placing the contents directly.

As you are sending a file a with extension `.xml`  from your multipart request 
so it should be get and written in that way.

**Steps you should do for getting your files items** 
(Either they are file or input parameters)

- Check Weather its a multipart request. proceed to next if yes get
- file extension (Not necessary but good if you check) then read its
- content using `parseRequest method` and
- then Write its content to file.

  `boolean isMultipartContent = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
  if (!isMultipartContent) {
  out.println("You are not trying to upload<br/>");
  return;
  out.println("You are trying to upload<br/>");`

For reference You can view [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-a-servlet.html) but its only for a normal file, not for xml.
also [uploading xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10447266/how-to-call-a-url-with-multipart-request-on-server-side-where-instead-of-file-th) may help you.